# grep data in file for particular date range

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to search data in a file in given date range (25th May -26th May 2017)

2017-05-25 to 2017-05-26

It search the data but it searches other data as well which is not in this date range.
I am using below command for same.

```
sed -n '/2017-05-25/,/2017-05-26/p' /tmp/CGMJGFTS_FIN_NAM_PRODlog
```

This looks good

```
1_V9AGGSWDC16_112_2017_05_25-160523_1001293_464.csv:"CGMJGFTS_FIN_NAM_PROD"!@#"PATROL_GC"!@#"169.177.208.155"!@#""!@#"4100"!@#"169.177.208.155"!@#"ISQL"!@#"PATMON"!@#"2017-05-24"!@#"2017-05-24"!@#"1"!@#"SYBASE"!@#"CONDB"!@#"2017-05-25 00:01:16"
```

but it also search

```
@#"2"
1_V9AGGSWDC16_112_2017_05_28-160445_1001293_467.csv:"CGMJGFTS_FIN_NAM_PROD"!@#"PATROL_GC"!@#"169.177.208.155"!@#""!@#"4100"!@#"150.110.82.18"!@#"ISQL"!@#"DBA_LOCAL"!@#"**2017-05-27**
```

Comment: why does it look "good" ? - it contains `2017-05-24` which is not in the needed range. Post the input fragment (more lines)

Comment: That's not really a search over a date of ranges. It literally means "show all lines from the first line that matches '2017-05-25' to the first subsequent line that matches '2017-05-26'". If '2017-05-26' is absent, it will show to the end of the file. If '2017-05-25' is absent it will show nothing. `sed` doesn't really know anything at all about dates and arithmetic/comparisons involving them.

Answer (score 0):

Your current `sed` pattern will look for matches over multiple rows. (see @twalberg's comment).

---

If you're looking for individual lines that contain both of the dates (as literals), and with the assumption that said dates are in order (ie, older date listed first, newer date listed later in the line), you could try using a single regexp, eg:

```
sed -n '/2017-05-25.*2017-05-26/p' <filename>
```

For example:

```
$ cat tt
1.some_stuff.2017-05-24_some_more_stuff:2017-05-24;and the end
2.some_stuff.2017-05-25_some_more_stuff:2017-05-26;and the end   # should only find this row
3.some_stuff.2017-05-24_some_more_stuff:2017-05-26;and the end
4.some_stuff.2017-05-25_some_more_stuff:2017-05-27;and the end

$ sed -n '/2017-05-25.*2017-05-26/p' tt
2.some_stuff.2017-05-25_some_more_stuff:2017-05-26;and the end
```

And of course you've got other options besides `sed`, eg:

```
$ egrep "2017-05-25.*2017-05-26" tt
2.some_stuff.2017-05-25_some_more_stuff:2017-05-26;and the end

$ awk '/2017-05-25.*2017-05-26/ {print}' tt
2.some_stuff.2017-05-25_some_more_stuff:2017-05-26;and the end
```

---

If on the other hand you're looking for `sed` to find individual rows where dates (as literals) are within the range of 2 search dates, `sed` doesn't know anything about date math/comparisons (again, same thing @twalberg's commented on).

---

If none of the above addresses your issue, then you'll need to edit your question to provide more details of what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  And to that end I'd recommend you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to list down all the lines which has date as 2017-05-25 and 2017-05-26..the above command list only lines which has both the dates which i dont want

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense ... you want lines with both dates 2017-05-25 **and** 2017-05-26 ... but my suggested examples aren't acceptable because they provide what you want, namely lines with both dates 2017-05-25 **and** 2017-05-26 ???  I suggest you take a look at that link I provided, then update your question with ... at a minimum ... a set of sample data and the desired results

Answer (score 0):

I think, You want to print those lines which will have either `2017-05-25` or `2017-05-26` as date. If I'm correct then below command might help you. :)

```
egrep "(2017-05-25.*|2017-05-26.*)" file
```